# Casting from int64_t to double to int64_t again changes it's value

Tags: c++

```
int main()
{
  int64_t iaVal = (int64_t)9007199258935295;
  double daVal = (double)iaVal;
  std::cout << "original " << iaVal << "\tAfter conversion  "  << (std::int64_t)daVal <<  std::endl;
}
```

Output :

```
Original          9007199258935295  
After conversion  9007199258935296
```

How can I get the correct value from double?

Comment: Short answer: You can't! A 64-bit integer can hold more significant decimal digits than a standard IEEE (64-bit) double precision floating-point representation.

Comment: Related: [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Comment: Have you tried `long double`?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52762881/is-long-double-in-c-an-implementation-of-ieees-binary128

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I get the correct value from double ?

You cannot. The value has been lost when you converted it into a type that cannot precisely represent it. Consider analogous sitation: I have converted an `int` value 42 to the `bool` value `true`. When I convert it back to integer, it changes it's value to 1. How can I convert to the correct value? (I cannot)

You have these options:

- Only use values that are representable as `double`. 9007199258935295 is not representable as 64 bit binary floating point (IEEE-754)<sup>1</sup>. All 32 bit integers are representable.
- Use `long double` instead. Both x86 80 bit extended floating point, and 128 bit IEEE-754 floating point can represent all 64 bit integers.
- Instead of finite precision, use arbitrary precision arithmetic in which case you don't need to be concerned of lack of precision. C++ standard library does not provide implementation of arbitrary precision arithmetic.

---

<sup>1</sup> Although the IEE-754 standard is ubiquitous, technically the precision of no foating point type is defined by the C++ language. It is defined by the language implementation.

Answer (score 5):

From [Double-precision floating-point format: IEEE 754 double-precision binary floating-point format: binary64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format#IEEE_754_double-precision_binary_floating-point_format:_binary64) [**emphasis** mine]:

> Double-precision binary floating-point is a commonly used format on PCs, due to its wider range over single-precision floating point, in spite of its performance and bandwidth cost. It is commonly known simply as double. The IEEE 754 standard specifies a binary64 as having:
>
> - Sign bit: 1 bit
> - Exponent: 11 bits
> - **Significand precision:** 53 bits (52 explicitly stored)

a double-precision IEEE 754-compliant binary floating-point have a significand precision of 53 bits, whereas a signed integer of 64 bits (`int64_t`) naturally have a precision of 64 bits, meaning the former will not be able to represent all values of the latter. Moreover, floating points in C++ are not even guaranteed to be IEE 754 compliant (implementation-defined), but for implementations for which they are

```
#include <limits>
static_assert(std::numeric_limits<double>::is_iec559, "");
```

as per the significant argument above, a `double` would be able to represent all numbers of a 32-bit integer.